# Apache hadoop releases

Tags: apache, hadoop

Two or so years ago I understood what was going on.  But now I look at the Apache release page and I see several active streams: 2.5 2.6 and 2.7.  The content of these versions is more fully called out in the Apache roadmap.  I see that 2.6.4 is more recent than 2.7.2.  I also note that 2.6 was never marked as stable, but 2.7.2 is stable.  So, what does it mean for a release to be marked stable?  Are the minor releases just branches from the main trunk whose work might be joined up later on? Is there a document that explains this?

Answer (score 0):

The Release Policy for Hadoop is a bit hard to understand. You are right there are multiple active streams. The reason is, that Apache provides stability updates / bugfixes for older versions of hadoop.

The Patter for the Version is X.Y.Z (X=Mayor-Version, Y=Minor-Version, Z=Revision). So we have the "old" version 2.6 and new Version 2.7 with some new Features. If there are Bugs encounterd and fixed in 2.7 which can also be fixed in 2.6 they provide new revision for both (2.7.1 and 2.6.1).

2.6.4 is more recent because it was build and released later. But 2.7.1 provides the newest featuers.

Regarding your last question:
All Releases are intended for everyday usage by non-developers. Releases that marked as stable has all features fully implemented and stable. Releases like 2.6 are stable in the matter of system stability but some features like APIs oder drivers are not fully implemented and can not be used completly.